# Python Reportlab units, cm and inch, are translated differently

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

If I draw two PDF files with ReportLab (vers. 3.2.0) with either cm or inch settings I get two different PDFs.

I have two functions that to me look exactly equal. In one I place the text into position (5.0*inch, 10.0*inch) and in the other I place them in (5.0*2.54*cm, 10.0*2.54*cm). Obviously, I use 2.54 to translate the lengths from inches to centimeters.

The problem is that the text gets placed in different positions. Am I missing something, is this a bug or what's going on?

Below I have added the code that replicates my problem as well as pictures of the two outcomes.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch, cm
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4

def cm_test():
    c = canvas.Canvas("inch.pdf", pagesize=A4)
    c.translate(inch, inch)
    text_object = c.beginText(5.0*inch, 10.0*inch)
    text_object.textLine("INCH: text located here")
    c.drawText(text_object)
    c.save()

def inch_test():
    c = canvas.Canvas("cm.pdf", pagesize=A4)
    c.translate(cm, cm)
    text_object = c.beginText(5.0*2.54*cm, 10.0*2.54*cm)
    text_object.textLine("CM: text located here")
    c.drawText(text_object)
    c.save()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cm_test()
    inch_test()
```

[Pic 1: Outcome of function cm_test()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC10n.png)

[Pic 2: Outcome of function inch_test()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk4z1.png)

Comment: As B8vrede pointed out in his answer, the difference is caused by the c.translate() part. If I change the cm_test() function to have c.translate(2.54*cm, 2.54*cm) then the PDFs become equal again, because the origin is set in the same position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the bug, the reason the text is printed at different places as the following lines:

```
c.translate(inch, inch)
c.translate(cm, cm)
```

These statements move the canvas origin 1 cm/inch up and right. As Reportlab draws based on this origin the text is placed at different position.

Comment: Oh, that's right! I actually should have known that, because often people set the canvas starting from a specific point, for example (inch, 2*inch). 
For some reason I had forgotten what translate() means and thought it is used to tell ReporLab to interpret lengths in inches or in centimeters. For some reason I thought that you couldn't place text or pictures using inch or cm multipliers without first telling how to interpret the coordinates. I probably got confused because there is c.beginText(inches, inches) separately. 

Thank you B8vrede for your quick answer!